# Sendng CAN BCM Cyclic Message Has No Frame Contents

Tags: c++, can-bus

I need to transmit 1200 identical CAN messages, with 5ms between each message. This is to arm a motor to start. Because of the timing required, I switched from

```
sockfd = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);
```

to

sockfd = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM);

Using a CAN sniffer, the 1200 messages are being sent at 5ms intervals. The data field has the correct data that I specified, but the 32-bit CAN_ID field is 0x00000000 instead of 0x00000201.

The code I wrote to send a TX_SETUP is shown below.

```
   // these are placed here for testing
   unsigned char priority = 0;
   unsigned char srcaddr = 0;
   unsigned char destaddr = 2;
   unsigned objaddr = ESC::enumPWM;

   struct {
      struct bcm_msg_head msg_head;
      struct can_frame frame[4];
   } txmsg;

   txmsg.msg_head.opcode = TX_SETUP;
   txmsg.msg_head.nframes = 1;

   // set flags first, set EFF for extended frame, no
   // RTR, no ERR.
   txmsg.frame[0].can_id = CAN_EFF_FLAG;
   txmsg.frame[0].can_id |= ((0x1F & priority) << 24);
   txmsg.frame[0].can_id |= (srcaddr << 16);
   txmsg.frame[0].can_id |= (destaddr << 8);
   txmsg.frame[0].can_id |= objaddr;

   txmsg.msg_head.flags = SETTIMER | STARTTIMER | TX_CP_CAN_ID;
   txmsg.msg_head.count = 1200;
   txmsg.msg_head.ival1.tv_sec = 0;
   txmsg.msg_head.ival1.tv_usec = 5000;
   txmsg.msg_head.ival2.tv_sec = 0;
   txmsg.msg_head.ival2.tv_usec = 0;

   // configure the data to send
   txmsg.frame[0].can_dlc = 2;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[0] = 0x04;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[1] = 0x4C;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[2] = 0;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[3] = 0;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[4] = 0;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[5] = 0;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[6] = 0;
   txmsg.frame[0].data[7] = 0;

   int err = write(can->sockfd, &txmsg, sizeof(txmsg));
```

Any idea why the message is transmitting incorrectly?

Comment: Just a check: Is `err == sizeof txmsg` after `write`?

Comment: Some fields of the `msg_head` structure seem to be uninitialized, e.g. `.flags`. If `.flags` contains `TX_CP_CAN_ID`, the CAN ID will be read from `.msg_head.can_id` instead of `.frame[0].can_id`. (Not sure because your code snippet is not a [mre].)

Comment: Anyway, make sure to explicitly set the RTR flag to zero. If it is set, data will be discarded regardless of DLC.